# After reading in values from an array, I must output the values less than or equal to a threshold. But it prints extra characters

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I will provide my code below, however I needed to create an array based on the size that the user inputs.
Example, if the user inputs "5" I know that I have to make an array of size "5."
After that, I have to call a method that will read "5" numbers into an array.
Then the user will input a threshold number. I need to use that threshold to output any number that is less than or equal to that number.
Example, If the user inputs "100" I know that I have to input all numbers in the array that are less than or equal to "100."

Final example all put together:

User input: 5 //length of array
User input: 100 //I will have to print all numbers in the array that are < or = to 100

array name: myArr[]

5 numbers that will go into myArr[]: 50 60 140 200 75

I need to print: 50 60 75

what my code actually prints: 50 60 75 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

This is my code. It prints out the correct numbers however it also adds a bunch of zeros at the end

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static void getUserValues(int[] myArr, int arrSize, Scanner scnr){
        for(int i=0; i< arrSize; i++){
        myArr[i]=scnr.nextInt(); 
     }
      
   }
   
    public static void outputIntsLessThanOrEqualToThreshold( int[] userValues, int userValsSize, int upperThreshold){
     
        for(int i = 0; i<userValues.length; i++) {
           if(upperThreshold >=userValues[i]) {
              System.out.print(userValues[i]+ " ");
         }
      }
      
   }
   
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       int[] userValues = new int[20];
       int upperThreshold;
       int numVals;
 
       numVals = scnr.nextInt();
       getUserValues(userValues, numVals, scnr);

       upperThreshold = scnr.nextInt();
       outputIntsLessThanOrEqualToThreshold(userValues, numVals, upperThreshold);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create the array based on the `numVals` from the input. Currently, your array is larger than the actual number of inputs, so you get a lot of trailing zeros.

```java
int numVals = scnr.nextInt();
int[] userValues = new int[numVals];
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLTsMwEDwnX7HqKVVL5CIKh1AkDhyQQBxSuFQ9mNRNXBwn@FEoqN8e7MQtaQkIKZLlzezM7I5XeI1PVouXqqJ5WQgFK1MItaIsjBPMORGR75f6mdEEEoalhHtMOXz6nitKhZU51gVdQErUoyTiCTNNZEC5ms0h31wLMQRzASxETD/IEBwzyISLvuXyloUA2wAUJoAic1zu4OYyGDQoryab0bkB2d6Qk3d1y1XQj8zfrW@@Tl@FVqW2QHlHpJxmmD@Im1eN2bSYZoLIrGALZ1fv/Tee3V02xutKWRKxb/vd/jdTyAhPVdYehC4hOCSCq0mrxczokF68kYrkoZkhLIXRCA5QMIAe9Or57QL@WEJucgtiZShSMycWqWwU2mEY95y87fIJnDTlNf/P4XdVrnO7o85UjtfqJGzZtc0t7PDptFNwqGHzWiz2aHFdqv9KvFPlKN7I7nNbVWN/jOAcwegMwSlCcDH2Rwh9AQ)

Answer (score 0):

You defined an array with a fixed size. So after inserting all your input values, the rest of the positions will be filled with trailing zeros. To avoid this, dynamic array maybe an option. Please check the following code snippet:

```
class LabProgram {
    public static void getUserValues(ArrayList<Integer> myArr, int arrSize, Scanner scnr) {
        while(myArr.size() < arrSize){
            myArr.add(scnr.nextInt());
        }
    }   
    
    public static void outputIntsLessThanOrEqualToThreshold(ArrayList<Integer> userValues, int userValsSize, int upperThreshold){
        
        for(int i = 0; i<userValsSize; i++) {
            if(upperThreshold >=userValues.get(i)) {
               System.out.print(userValues.get(i)+ " ");
          }
       }    
    
   }    
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

       ArrayList<Integer> userValues = new ArrayList<>();
       int upperThreshold;
       int numVals;
 
       numVals = scnr.nextInt();
       getUserValues(userValues, numVals, scnr);

       upperThreshold = scnr.nextInt();
       outputIntsLessThanOrEqualToThreshold(userValues, numVals, upperThreshold);
    }
}
```